# Passing more than one datagrid to a function in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have 2 or more `GridView`s which are bound to different tables as datasources.

There is a template field with a checkbox in each of the `GridView`. Upon checking the 
checkbox, the data from that particular `GridView` row gets saved in the database.

I want a single save button to save all the checked checkbox row values 
from different `GridView`s.

If I happen to check a checkbox from the first grid and then 
select another checkbox from a second grid, upon clicking a single save button
I must be able to save these values to the database.

However the new table created has columns from the tables serving as the datasources
to these two different `GridView`s.

So I thought if there could be a way to pass the `GridView` ID and the checked checkbox ID from the selected `GridView` I could save my self from replicating the same save code again.

However both the gridViews have the same number of columns with the same datatypes.

Is there a way for me to pass the selected `GridView` id and 
its checked checkbox ID to a single save button?

Comment: You're going to need to rephrase your question. What are you trying to solve? What issue are you running into? Do you have any code?

Comment: There will be no way to answer your question as it stands.  Right now the answer is simply "Yes".  If you want anything more specific you have to show the code you have now and exactly why you can't do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a function that one parameter will be a Windows.Forms.DataGridView, or better, send the datasource.

```
GetGrid(dtgName.DataSource);

Public void GetGrid(SqlDataSource Data){

}
```